# ffmpeg naming output file with custom name

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I am using ffmpeg on JEtson Xavier NX to split a video into frames as follows

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv  -r 30 %2d.jpg
```

This generates output as

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg...etc
```

However I want to start the counter from a custom number and not 1.
For example

```
32.jpg
33.jpg
....etc
```

The starting number of the frame should based on some variable that I want to initialize and then it should proceed labeling sequentially from there. How do I do this?

Comment: try to rename them with os.rename() , simple ;)

Comment: @KunalSharma Is there no way to start off the naming itself from a custom value? through a variable or something?

Comment: This might help: [Can I set the start number for image sequence output?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19511)